# Anomaly Detection in Variables Through PCA and identifying the cause of Anomaly happened (Eg through:Hotelling T2)

Tags: r, loading, pca, anomaly-detection

PCA Anomaly detection and identifying which variable in the data frame is really contributing to the abnormal behavior in Principal component-1 at observation level.Example is shown in the link for observation 34 in the last image. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2014/ay/c3ay41907j#tab1.

So I have applied PCA over Wine data where the data consist of wine type and various characteristic of wine respectively. Once we apply pca over the data we have PC1 PC2 and many components. when we plot PC1 we get to see for a particular observation(Eg : Observation 34) we are getting anomaly pattern. so we need to understand why which variable has cause this is anomaly data point. till now I have computed loading which gives overall Contribution of variable,where I want to for every variable contribution of every column respectively

```
# Creating Wine data frame for PCA Anomaly Contribution plot
rm(list=ls())
Wine_Type <- c("ARG-BNS1",  "ARG-DDA1", "ARG-FFL1", "ARG-FLM1", "ARG-ICR1", "ARG-SAL1", "AUS-CAV1", "AUS-EAG1", "AUS-HAR1", "AUS-IB41", "AUS-KIL1", "AUS-KIR1", "AUS-NUG1", "AUS-SOC1", "AUS-TGH1", "AUS-VAF1", "AUS-WBL1", "AUS-WES1", "CHI-CDD1", "CHI-CDM1", "CHI-CMO1", "CHI-CSU1", "CHI-GNE1", "CHI-IND1", "CHI-LJO1", "CHI-S151", "CHI-SCH1", "CHI-SHE1", "CHI-SUN1", "CHI-UND1", "CHI-UTA1", "CHI-VDA1", "CHI-VDS1", 'SOU-HHI1', "SOU-INS1", "SOU-KWV1", 'SOU-NED1', 'SOU-PDM1', "SOU-ROO1", "SOU-RW21", "SOU-SAV1", "SOU-SIM1", "SOU-SPI1", "SOU-SRE1")

Ethanol <- c(13.6199999,    14.0600004, 13.7399998, 13.9499998, 14.4700003, 14.6099997, 13.6499996, 14.1199999, 13.1300001, 13.49,  15.0900002, 14.6300001, 13.6300001, 13.6700001, 14.4300003, 13.4499998, 13.8299999, 13.8500004, 13.9700003, 12.8400002, 14.1899996, 14.1300001, 13.6599998, 14.2700005, 13.8400002, 13.5799999, 13.2299995, 13.6099997, 13.7700005, 13.6199999, 13.5100002, 12.79,  14.6300001, 13.96,  14.0500002, 14.0200005, 13.9799995, 14.5,   13.8999996, 14.2200003, 13.8000002, 14.4499998, 14.3599997, 14.25)

Total_acid <- c(3.53999996, 3.74000001, 3.26999998, 3.66000009, 3.66000009, 3.45000005, 4.30999994, 3.88000011, 3.82999992, 3.69,   3.98000002, 4.78000021, 4.63999987, 3.86999989, 4.51000023, 4.34000015, 4.21999979, 4.15999985, 3.53999996, 3.22000003, 3.4000001,  3.61999989, 3.07999992, 3.43000007, 3.04999995, 3.24000001, 3.03999996, 3.07999992, 3.36999989, 3.49000001, 3.42000008, 2.99000001, 3.1400001,  4.55000019, 3.5,    3.88000011, 4.36000013, 4.42000008, 4.0999999,  4.05999994, 3.58999991, 3.83999991, 3.81999993, 3.56999993)
Volatile_acid<- c(0.289999992,  0.589999974,    0.469999999,    0.469999999,    0.379999995,    0.519999981,    0.319999993,    0.370000005,    0.270000011,    0.32,   0.469999999,    0.430000007,    0.709999979,    0.540000021,    0.400000006,    0.460000008,    0.330000013,    0.360000014,    0.289999992,    0.340000004,    0.349999994,    0.330000013,    0.280000001,    0.439999998,    0.25999999, 0.239999995,    0.340000004,    0.280000001,    0.300000012,    0.209999993,    0.319999993,    0.370000005,    0.439999998,    1.02999997, 0.379999995,    0.409999996,    0.430000007,    0.360000014,    0.649999976,    0.419999987,    0.349999994,    0.340000004,    0.319999993,    0.479999989)         
Malic_acid <- c(0.889999986,    0.239999995,    -0.07,  0.090000004,    0.610000014,    0.159999996,    0.180000007,    0.360000014,    0.400000006,    0.5,    0.439999998,    0.519999981,    0.189999998,    0.159999996,    0.310000002,    0.469999999,    0.49000001, 0.170000002,    0.479999989,    0.419999987,    0.460000008,    0.310000002,    0.419999987,    0.449999988,    0.469999999,    0.529999971,    0.419999987,    0.50999999, 0.319999993,    0.449999988,    0.540000021,    0.289999992,    0.379999995,    -0.620000005,   0.479999989,    0.449999988,    0.280000001,    0.529999971,    0.189999998,    0.280000001,    0.550000012,    0.709999979,    0.50999999, 0.389999986)
pH <- c(3.71000004, 3.73000002, 3.86999989, 3.78999996, 3.70000005, 3.92000008, 3.5999999,  3.70000005, 3.66000009, 3.7,    3.67000008, 3.52999997, 3.6400001,  3.6500001,  3.70000005, 3.48000002, 3.54999995, 3.53999996, 3.6400001,  3.71000004, 3.72000003, 3.6400001,  3.68000007, 3.75999999, 3.71000004, 3.61999989, 3.76999998, 3.6400001,  3.68000007, 3.57999992, 3.63000011, 3.70000005, 3.75,   3.88000011, 3.81999993, 3.68000007, 3.66000009, 3.61999989, 3.66000009, 3.63000011, 3.82999992, 3.75999999, 3.8499999,  3.70000005)                     
Latic_acid <- c(0.779999971,    1.25,   1.13,   1,  0.810000002,    1.75999999, 1.37,   1.01999998, 1.13,   1.02,   1.00999999, 0.839999974,    1.78999996, 1.22000003, 1.49000001, 1.16999996, 1.13,   0.959999979,    0.779999971,    1.19000006, 0.850000024,    0.819999993,    0.910000026,    0.790000021,    0.800000012,    0.829999983,    1.08000004, 0.939999998,    0.930000007,    0.800000012,    0.839999974,    1.26999998, 0.939999998,    2.95000005, 1.13999999, 1.00999999, 1.44000006, 0.980000019,    1.17999995, 1.25,   1.13999999, 1.00999999, 1.02999997, 0.949999988)            
Rest_sugar <- c(1.46000004, 2.42000008, 1.51999998, 4.17000008, 1.25,   1.39999998, 3.79999995, 4.32000017, 3.99000001, 6.4,    1.05999994, 1.20000005, 1.45000005, 0.620000005,    5.61999989, 1.27999997, 1.19000006, 2.58999991, 1.14999998, 1.37,   1.75,   1.77999997, 4.23999977, 1.51999998, 2.07999992, 2.45000005, 1.05999994, 4.0999999,  2.74000001, 1.37,   1.14999998, 1.15999997, 2.19000006, 2.3599999,  1.60000002, 1.45000005, 1.01999998, 0.75999999, 1.35000002, 1.53999996, 2.27999997, 2.11999989, 2.68000007, 1.92999995)
Citric_acid <- c(0.310000002,   0.180000007,    0.389999986,    0.409999996,    0.140000001,    0.100000001,    0.239999995,    0.319999993,    0.340000004,    0.13,   -0.039999999,   -0.050000001,   0.159999996,    0.370000005,    0.430000007,    -0.01,  0.090000004,    0.200000003,    0.119999997,    0.119999997,    0.170000002,    0.25999999, 0.100000001,    0.059999999,    0.209999993,    0.25999999, 0.209999993,    0.059999999,    0.300000012,    0.25999999, 0.090000004,    0.200000003,    0.200000003,    0.25,   -0.039999999,   0.07,   0.059999999,    0.159999996,    0.079999998,    0.090000004,    0.079999998,    0.200000003,    -0.02,  0.07)            
Co2 <- c(85.6100006,    175.199997, 513.73999,  379.399994, 154.880005, 156.300003, 462.619995, 244.149994, 212,    419.38, 48.0200005, 154.820007, 243.960007, 563.400024, 347.880005, 263.459991, 288.970001, 272.190002, 210.529999, 338.869995, 245.070007, 183.699997, 353.529999, 247.289993, 399.070007, 475.890015, 603.320007, 400.470001, 180.139999, 495.329987, 388.079987, 390.149994, 228.389999, 282.73999,  510.079987, 243.580002, 452.959991, 184.940002, 183.059998, 246.339996, 297.540009, 104.269997, 510.089996, 260.079987)                   
Density <- c(0.99000001,    1,  0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0.99000001, 1,  1,  0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 0.99000001, 1,  1,  1,  0.99000001)
Total.polyphenol.index <- c(60.9199982, 70.6399994, 63.5900002, 73.3000031, 71.6900024, 71.7900009, 59.5999985, 59.5,   59.4199982, 63.86,  70.0999985, 72.3700027, 55.0699997, 63.0400009, 63.5200005, 62.6899986, 59.0800018, 83.5100021, 64.3099976, 53.0999985, 66.8199997, 64.8300018, 52.1599998, 63.75,  56.5499992, 53.1300011, 54.8899994, 54.2599983, 64.8000031, 58.8300018, 58.8100014, 50.4399986, 61.9399986, 44.6800003, 62.5800018, 60.8699989, 62.3499985, 60.1300011, 58.4700012, 57.0800018, 60.3600006, 68.6800003, 67.7699966, 57.8600006) 
Glycerol <- c(9.72000027,   10.0500002, 10.9200001, 9.68999958, 10.8100004, 10.1899996, 10.6599998, 11.0699997, 8.89000034, 10.35,  11.4300003, 11.6400003, 9.59000015, 11.2799997, 10.9300003, 9.46000004, 11.1000004, 10.4499998, 10.5799999, 8.80000019, 10.1099997, 9.85000038, 9.53999996, 9.93000031, 9.47999954, 9.32999992, 9.02000046, 9.38000011, 10.3299999, 9.86999989, 9.76000023, 8.11999989, 10.0500002, 8.22999954, 10.1000004, 10.6099997, 10.6199999, 12.5200005, 11.7200003, 10.2399998, 10.4700003, 11.1800003, 10.5799999, 9.93999958)              
Methanol <- c(0.159999996,  0.200000003,    0.180000007,    0.230000004,    0.200000003,    0.189999998,    0.25,   0.25,   0.230000004,    0.26,   0.189999998,    0.280000001,    0.25,   0.140000001,    0.300000012,    0.180000007,    0.219999999,    0.239999995,    0.180000007,    0.170000002,    0.180000007,    0.219999999,    0.180000007,    0.209999993,    0.189999998,    0.150000006,    0.150000006,    0.170000002,    0.170000002,    0.189999998,    0.180000007,    0.129999995,    0.150000006,    0.170000002,    0.25,   0.200000003,    0.219999999,    0.219999999,    0.180000007,    0.219999999,    0.239999995,    0.209999993,    0.270000011,    0.200000003)
Tartaric.acid <- c(1.74000001,  1.58000004, 1.24000001, 2.25999999, 1.22000003, 0.899999976,    1.80999994, 1.64999998, 2.11999989, 1.81,   1.47000003, 2.11999989, 1.36000001, 1.00999999, 1.80999994, 2.13000011, 1.54999995, 2.47000003, 1.72000003, 1.85000002, 1.48000002, 1.83000004, 1.38,   1.48000002, 1.65999997, 1.63,   1.55999994, 1.41999996, 1.62,   1.77999997, 1.29999995, 1.46000004, 1.30999994, 0.910000026,    1.22000003, 1.30999994, 1.76999998, 1.55999994, 1.40999997, 1.5,    1.70000005, 1.52999997, 2.01999998, 1.42999995)
country <- c("Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Australia",   "Australia","Australia","Australia","Australia","Australia","Australia","Australia","Australia",    "Australia","Australia","Australia","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile",    "Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile","South_Africa","South_Africa","South_Africa",   "South_Africa","South_Africa","South_Africa","South_Africa","South_Africa","South_Africa",  "South_Africa","South_Africa")
wdata <- data.frame(Wine_Type,Ethanol,Total_acid,Volatile_acid,Malic_acid,pH,Latic_acid,Rest_sugar,Citric_acid,Co2,Density,Total.polyphenol.index,Glycerol,Methanol,Tartaric.acid,country)
wdata
wdata$country <- as.factor(wdata$country)
df_index <- wdata[,c("Wine_Type","country")] # removing column which are not for PCA
dx <- wdata[,!names(wdata) %in% names(df_index)]
rownames(dx) <- df_index$Wine_Type  

# Normalising data for PCA Analysis
scaleContinuous = function(data) {
 data <- data[,sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))]
 data <- as.data.frame(data)

  binary = apply(data, 2, function(x) {all(x %in% 0:1)}) 
  data[!binary] = scale(data[!binary])
  return(data)
}
dx <- as.data.frame(dx)
dx <- scaleContinuous(dx)
```

[image: Data set View]

```
# Performing PCA 
pca_df <- princomp(dx, cor = T) 
summary(pca_df)  

# Getting Score & Loading from PCA Attributes
score_df <- as.data.frame(pca_df$scores)
loading_df <- as.matrix(pca_df$loadings)
```

## Visualising PC1 and PC2 and Loading for PC1 and PC2

```
plot(as.ts(score_df$Comp.1),main="First Principal Component", type = "l", col = "brown", lwd = 3)
```

[image: PC1 Line plot]

```
plot(as.ts(score_df$Comp.2),main="Second Principal Component", type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

[image: PC2 Line plot]

```
my_vector1=loading_df[,1]
my_vector2=loading_df[,2]
names(my_vector1)= rownames(loading_df)
names(my_vector2)= rownames(loading_df)
library(RColorBrewer)
coul = brewer.pal(9, "Paired")
```

## Contribution plot for PC1 and PC2.

```
 #   par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    a1=barplot(my_vector1, col=coul , las=1, names.arg="",main = paste("Weight/loading For PC1"))
    text(a1[,1], 0.2 ,srt = 90, adj= 1, xpd = TRUE, labels = names(dx) , cex=1.0)
```

[image: Contribution Plot for PC1]

a2=barplot(my_vector2, col=coul , las=1, names.arg="",main = paste("Weight/Loading For PC2"))
text(a2[,1], 0.2 ,srt = 90, adj= 1, xpd = TRUE, labels = names(dx) , cex=1.0)
[image: Contribution Plot For PC2]

So expected output is to compute the contribution of every variable for identified anomaly in PC1 at every observation. For reference a link is attached where Hotelling T2 is used to identify   it .https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2014/ay/c3ay41907j#tab1

[image: Expected Output for contribution plot]

So Expected is : how to compute a Hotelling T2 score or contribution plot for Observation No 34 as shown in PC1 Line plot using the formulae highlighted with red mark in the last Image and for more reference link is also attached respectively .

`Basically how to compute the below Equation shown in image`

[image: Equation to compute for Observation level]